# Instance method 'match(match:player:didChangeState:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'match(_:player:didChange:)' of protocol 'GKMatchDelegate'

Tags: swift, swift3

i have this function in my code:

```
func match(match: GKMatch, player playerID: String, didChangeState state: GKPlayerConnectionState) {
        if (match != self.match) {
            print("Wrong match")
            return
        }
```

and it gaves me this warning:

> Instance method 'match(match:player:didChangeState:)' nearly matches
>   optional requirement 'match(_:player:didChange:)' of protocol
>   'GKMatchDelegate'

and it offers me the possibility to make the *func* private, or to insert @nonobjc to silence the warning?
what should i do?

Comment: `func match(_ match: GKMatch, ...)` ? Lookup the documentation!

Comment: Don't think a down-vote was justified here. Apple keeps changing Swift. I got the same error with code that was copy-and-pasted from Apple's own iOS development with Swift tutorial. In my case this info was what saved me: http://aplus.rs/2016/swift-3-migration-tip-instance-method-dot-dot-dot-nearly-matches-warning/ I.e., type in the func name manually and let intellisense provide the current correct parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r (and the documentation)
just had to change it to:

```
 func match(_ match: GKMatch, player playerID: String, didChange state: GKPlayerConnectionState) {
        if (match != self.match) {
            print("Wrong match")
            return
        }
```